# ( status=deferred :25: Connection timed out ) issue with Postfix

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, postfix, centos6

I have postfix installed on a Centos server with 1 main ip 1.1.1.1 and a range of ips 2.2.2.0/24

The problem is : i can only send mail with the main ip 1.1.1.1, when i change it to another one from the range ex : 2.2.2.222 the mail stays in the queue ( status=deffered )

maillog error: to=, relay=none, delay=70314, delays=70164/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25: Connection timed out).

Additionnal infos : - No DNS setup yet - The block 2.2.2.0/24 is added by creating a new file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts called ifcfg-eth0-range0 and we've put all the ip adresses in it starting from 2.2.2.0 to 2.2.2.255 - I use to change the sending ip using "inet_interface = ip" on the /etc/postfix/main.cf

Could you please help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the proper routes on the server, otherwise it will probably try and send through the default router of your first IP range.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The 'ip route' command output is : _1.1.1.64/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 1.1.11.66_ <= the main ip  and _2.2.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 64.128.252.0_

Comment: Basically, the connection timed out issue means the traffic is not arriving, it could be a firewall or some other impediment to the traffic flow, but the first thing to check is that the proper routes exist.

Comment: I'm guessing the fact that you're coming from a source of 0 on the second range is also going to cause you problems.. 0 is not a valid IP address, just like 255. You can only use 1 to 254 in a /24

Comment: I will change it now and check, this is my route command output i dont know if its correct : 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
199.250.198.64  *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
64.128.252.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         199.250.198.65  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

Comment: Do you need to have both IP ranges on eth0? This is not the easiest thing in the world to set up correctly. Like I said though, the default gateway is the one from the original IP, so 64.X.X.0 will try and send through 199.X.X.65, which isn't easy, considering they are not on the same subnet, or range.

Comment: Problem was the x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.255 IPs on the Network Interfaces.
i start from .2 to .254 and restart the network service and it work's.
Thank you @NickW

Comment: Sweet! Glad to know you got it going.